# while($stmt->fetch()) Not fetching all data

Tags: php, fetch

I can't find the reason why my function is not getting all the results. When I go to the page to view the comment I only see the most resent one. If I then delete that comment the next newest comment appears. I'm sure it is something simple that I have not noticed.

```
function getComments($inPostID=null)
{
    $commentArray = array();

    if (!empty($inPostID))
    {
        //echo " Get comments for the post with the postID of ". $inPostID;
        $stmt = db::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE postID = ? ORDER BY commentDate DESC");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $inPostID);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->bind_result($commentID, $postID, $userID, $commentDate, $commentContent);
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            echo"HI ";
            $thisComment = new ViewComment($commentID, $postID, $userID, $commentDate, $commentContent);
            array_push($commentArray, $thisComment);
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }

    return $commentArray;
}
```

Comment: How many times does `"HI "` get echoed? And are you sure there more than one comment for that particular postID?

Comment: Did you check what the `$stmt->execute` resulted?

Comment: Only once, I put that there for the test. Yes I am sure. I checked it on the database and also when I remove the latest comment on the post, it then brings up the next latest comment for the post.

Comment: $stmt->execute returns NULL? Why would that be? It gets at least one result so the bind_param and the SQL statement must be fine?

Comment: I placed the var_dump after the bind $stmt = db::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE postID = ? ORDER BY commentDate DESC");
   $stmt->bind_param('i', $inPostID);
   $stmt->execute(); 
   var_dump($stmt->execute);

Comment: What happens if you substitute a `postID` in directly instead of the `?` in `->prepare("...`, and skip the `bind_param` line? Do you get more than one result?

Comment: I have fixed it and will post the answer in one hour when StackOverflow lets me. Please rate it so my rep goes up so I wont have to wait in the future. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured it out. I was opening a bind statement and then in the ViewComment() function opening another bind statement to get further info from other tables. The fix was to store the  bindResults into a array that will be populated by the while and then close that bind statement. Then loop through the amount of results the the while gives in a for loop that calls the ViewComment() with the pramitors being the array from the bindResults array.

Code is below.

```
function getComments($inPostID=null)
{
    $commentArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    if (!empty($inPostID))
    {
        //echo " Get comments for the post with the postID of ". $inPostID;
        $stmt = db::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE postID = ? ORDER BY commentDate DESC");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $inPostID);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($commentID, $postID, $userID, $commentDate, $commentContent);
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            $bindResults = array($commentID, $postID, $userID, $commentDate, $commentContent);
            array_push($tempArray, $bindResults);
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $total = count($tempArray);
        for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++)
        {
            $thisComment = new ViewComment($tempArray[$i][0], $tempArray[$i][1], $tempArray[$i][2], $tempArray[$i][3], $tempArray[$i][4]);
            array_push($commentArray, $thisComment);
        }
    }
    return $commentArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fetch() will fetch only one record, to fetch all the records Use fetchAll(), change your code like

```
while($stmt->fetchAll())
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll()

Comment: can you put print_r($stmt) before while statement and check the result set

Comment: mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => -1 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 1 [field_count] => 5 [errno] => 0 [error] => [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 1 )

Comment: print_r($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) put this code just below $stmt->execute();

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given

Comment: @RobinMichaelPoothurai He does not use `PDO` but `mysqli` :)

Comment: just doing some testing and when I comment out the two lines inside the while the echo loops to the amount of comments there should be for the post.

Comment: echo"HI ";
//$thisComment = new ViewComment($commentID, $postID, $userID, $commentDate, $commentContent);
//array_push($commentArray, $thisComment);

Comment: When I call new ViewComment() All that does is get further details from other tables and explodes the data to a readable format.

Comment: When I uncomment the 2 lines and add another echo "there " after array_push (to test if it reaches past the function) it echos Hi there, only once and only one comment

Comment: To view all my posts I have `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY postDate DESC';
   $qry = db::connect()->query($sql);
   while($row = $qry->fetch_assoc())
   {
    $myPost = new ViewPost($row['postID'], $row['postedByUserID'], $row['postTitle'], $row['postCatID'], $row['postDate'], $row['postContent']);
    array_push($postArray, $myPost);
   }` But when I need to add a WHERE clause into the SQL statement I can't use this way because I need to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: Anyone? Or is this now a dead question?

Comment: I have fixed it and will post the answer in one hour when StackOverflow lets me. Please rate it so my rep goes up so I wont have to wait in the future. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Please change 
array_push($commentArray, $thisComment);
to

foreach($thisComment as $k=>$v)
    array_push($commentArray, $v);

Comment: This did not work, thanks for the suggestion though. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have fixed it and will post the answer in one hour when StackOverflow lets me. Please rate it so my rep goes up so I wont have to wait in the future. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

i think you should have use the following

```
$stmt->bind_param(1, $inPostID);
```

instead of

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $inPostID);
```

Comment: I did try it, I'm up for trying anything. output from var_dump($stmt); before its executed `object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (9) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }` Placed after `object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (9) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }`

Comment: Any ideas? I cant see the problem

Comment: I have fixed it and will post the answer in one hour when StackOverflow lets me. Please rate it so my rep goes up so I wont have to wait in the future. Thanks for your help guys!